# Extract cityname from address string

Tags: r, excel

Is there a way to extract the cityname from an address string that is sometimes inconsistent. Most of the time the cityname is the last word of the string, but not always. For example:

```
Streetname 8, 1234 AA, Amsterdam
Streetname 10, 1234 BB, Rotterdam ZH
```

Therefore, I just want to check whether the address string contains one of ~10 possible citynames. If so, that particular cityname has to be printed in a new column. 
Who can help me achieve this in either Excel of R?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `R`:

```
df = data.frame(Adres = c('Streetname 8, 1234 AA, Amsterdam','Streetname 10, 1234 BB, Rotterdam ZH'))
df$Stad <- stringr::str_extract(df$Adres, "(?<=, )[A-Za-z]+")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                     Adres          Stad
1         Streetname 8, 1234 AA, Amsterdam     Amsterdam
2     Streetname 10, 1234 BB, Rotterdam ZH     Rotterdam
```

Online [demo](https://repl.it/repls/ConsciousConventionalLifecycles)

---

This would work under the condition that your city names are a single word. Would you have cities like "Den Bosch" or "s-Hertogenbosch", you could use another pattern:

```
(?<=, )\D+?(?=( [A-Z]*)?$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This could, for example, lead to:

```
                                         Adres             Stad
1             Streetname 8, 1234 AA, Amsterdam        Amsterdam
2         Streetname 10, 1234 BB, Rotterdam ZH        Rotterdam
3 Streetname 10, 1234 BB, 's-Hertogenbosch BRA 's-Hertogenbosch
4        Streetname 10, 1234 BB, Den Bosch BRA        Den Bosch
```

In case you want to exclude certain cities, you can build a pattern that *includes* cities as an OR statement, for example:

```
(?<=, )(Rotterdam|Amsterdam|Den Bosch|'s-Hertogenbosch)(?=.*$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This could result in:

```
                                         Adres             Stad
1             Streetname 8, 1234 AA, Amsterdam        Amsterdam
2         Streetname 10, 1234 BB, Rotterdam ZH        Rotterdam
3            Streetname 19, 1234 CC, Almere FL             <NA>
4 Streetname 10, 1234 BB, 's-Hertogenbosch BRA 's-Hertogenbosch
5        Streetname 10, 1234 BB, Den Bosch BRA        Den Bosch
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VBA `Split()` function, as in this simple example:

```
Sub test()
Dim Temp As String
Dim LArray() As String
Dim LLArray() As String
Dim Result As String

  Temp = Range("B2").Value
  LArray = Split(Trim(Temp), ",")         # Split the address (the city name seems to be the third entry
                                          # Be cautious: the first item of an array is A(0), the second is A(1) and the third is A(2)
  LLArray = Split(Trim(LArray(2)), " ")   # Once you have the cityname, it may consist of one name
                                          # or it consists of the name, followed by something else, and you just need the first entry (A(0))
  Result = LLArray(0)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this VBA code within a normal module:

```
Public Function ExtractCity(Target As Range) As String

    Dim Cities As Variant
    Dim City As Variant

    Cities = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")

    For Each City In Cities
        If InStr(Target, City) > 0 Then
            ExtractCity = City
            Exit For
        End If
    Next City

End Function
```

- Place your 10 cities in the range `A1:A10` on the worksheet named `Sheet1`.
- Add your addresses in cells `D1:D2`.
- In cell `E1` enter this formula:  `=ExtractCity(D1)`